# How can I remove font styling of external embedded form?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hubspot

This is a weird one I'm scratching my head on.  I have a WordPress page that has a HubSpot embedded form.  My theme allows dark mode and works well, but when it goes to dark mode the embedded HubSpot form doesn't change.  I kind of get it, but... I just can't have it like this.  Is there a way that I can strip or override the form's colors or something?

Here's the page:  https://datadelivery.app

Comment: you really need to use some external service to make a single form? ... 0_o

Comment: @FlashThunder if I understand correctly the plugin integrates email interaction with a CRM so the form isn't there just for the user to send a message, but to record that as well.

Comment: @AHaworth Exactly.  There's a LOT going on with it behind the scenes.  Makes it easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HubSpot form is embedded into your site, it had no way of knowing when your site's theme is changed. You will need to add some custom CSS to change the form's style when dark-mode is enabled. From the given link, the class `.is-dark-theme` is added to the `<html>` tag whenever dark-mode is enabled. So you should be able to add CSS to style your form whenever this class is used. For example, the code below changes the form's labels to white-text.

```
.is-dark-theme .hs-form * {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

You should be able to add CSS for other classes used in the form to change the colors to match your site's dark-mode theme.

Comment: So put that as extra css in the theme customization?

Comment: Yes. And since the form uses inline-CSS, you might need to add the **!important** rule to your style. So, **color: #ffffff !important;**